# atlassian's Bitbucket service unable to start (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, command-line

On my CentOS 7 Server i installed Bitbucket, for some reason it crashed two days ago, i am trying to get it back running on my server but faced some difficulties enabling the service with the cmldlets :

```
   systemctl enable bitbucket.service
   systemctl start bitbucket.service
```

The latter returning the message :

> Control Process exited, code=exited status=203/EXEC

when i enter my bitbucket credentials from the `bitbucket.properties` file.

What could be the problem and what could be the solution to this case ?

Thank you for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when a systemd service exits with `code=exited status=`, it means that the process ended with a non-zero exit code and you should investigate the application.  However in the case of codes 200-242, these are [special systemd exit codes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20exit%20codes).

Exit code 203 means that systemd couldn't start the process.  This often means that an executable is missing or doesn't have execute permissions.

Use `systemctl cat bitbucket.service` and inspect the service files.  Adding the output to your question would help.  The problem is likely in one of the `ExecStart=` or `ExecStartPre=` lines. Ensure that each command has a full path (`/bin/ls` instead of `ls`). Also ensure each command exists and is executable.  Try running the commands yourself to see if there's a problem.

I think the `bitbucket.properties` file doesn't have anything to do with the issue yet.  Because the main process is not starting, it hasn't tried to open that file.

Comment: i found the issue actually it was the ExecStart not pointing on the right JRE version ! thx anyways!

Comment: Perfect.  Glad you found it.  That's exactly what it sounded like... `ExecStart=` was pointing at something that didn't exist and so it could never be launched.